# How to use multiple AWS accounts from the command line?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I've got two different apps that I am hosting (well the second one is about to go up) on Amazon EC2.

How can I work with both accounts at the command line (Mac OS X) but keep the EC2 keys & certificates separate?  Do I need to change my environment variables before each ec2-* command?

Would using an alias and having it to the setting of the environment in-line work?  Something like: `alias ec2-describe-instances1 = export EC2_PRIVATE_KEY=/path; ec2-describe-instances`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You should be able to use the following command-options in lieu of the `EC2_PRIVATE_KEY` (and even `EC2_CERT`) environment variables:

- `-K <private key>`
- `-C <certificate>`

You can put these inside aliases, e.g.

```
alias ec2-describe-instances1 ec2-describe-instances -K /path/to/key.pem
```

Answer (score 536):

You can work with two accounts by creating two [profiles](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-started.html#cli-multiple-profiles) on the aws command line.
It will prompt you for your [AWS Access Key ID, AWS Secret Access Key](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/managing-aws-access-keys.html) and desired region, so have them ready.

Examples:

```
$ aws configure --profile account1
$ aws configure --profile account2
```

You can then switch between the accounts by passing the profile on the command.

```
$ aws dynamodb list-tables --profile account1
$ aws s3 ls --profile account2
```

Note:

If you name the profile to be `default` it will become **default profile** i.e. when no `--profile` param in the command.

---

#### More on default profile

If you spend more time using *account1*, you can make it the default by setting the AWS_DEFAULT_PROFILE environment variable. When the default environment variable is set, you do not need to specify the profile on each command.

Linux, OS X Example:

```
$ export AWS_DEFAULT_PROFILE=account1
$ aws dynamodb list-tables
```

Windows Example:

```
$ set AWS_DEFAULT_PROFILE=account1
$ aws s3 ls
```

Comment: To configure region - here is list of region "codes" - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html

Answer (score 180):

## How to set "manually" multiple AWS accounts ?

**1) Get access** - key

[AWS Console > Identity and Access Management (IAM) > Your Security Credentials > Access Keys](https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home#security_credential)

**2) Set access** - file and content

`~/.aws/credentials`

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id={{aws_access_key_id}}
aws_secret_access_key={{aws_secret_access_key}}

[{{profile_name}}]
aws_access_key_id={{aws_access_key_id}}
aws_secret_access_key={{aws_secret_access_key}}
```

**3) Set profile** - file and content

`~/.aws/config`

```
[default]
region={{region}}
output={{output:"json||text"}}

[profile {{profile_name}}]
region={{region}}
output={{output:"json||text"}}
```

**4) Run** - file with params

[Install command-line app](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/getting-started-install.html) - and use [AWS Command Line](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/) it, for example for product [AWS EC2](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/)

`aws ec2 describe-instances` -- default

`aws ec2 describe-instances --profile {{profile_name}}` -- [{{profile_name}}]

---

Ref

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-profiles.html

Comment: @iBrianCox -- This information should preferably be merged into the most upvoted answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/34246053/1199564) because it allows a user to understand how to move settings from one profile to another if, for example, you started out with only the default profile and want to continue with dedicated, separate profiles.

Comment: @slm please read my comment above (was only able to do one mention per comment)

Comment: @mgd thank you for suggestion, but no - because at first that answer is not my - and second this is a different approach how to set it

Comment: @mgd Q can you more describe what you mean "one mention per comment" ?

Comment: What I meant was that in my first comment I intended to mention _both_ iBrianCox and slm (author and editor of the other answer respectively) but you are only allowed to do one mention per comment so I had to add another comment in order to mention both.
You are correct that your answer is a different approach but it is very helpful to know where the information is stored, in particular if you intend to copy settings between profiles.

Comment: After saving your `config` and `credentials` files, you may want to verify that all is working well. One nice way to do this is by running this command: `aws sts get-caller-identity` and then run it again with `aws sts get-caller-identity --profile blah` (where `blah` is a non-default profile). You should see a different UserId, Arn (and possibly account, depending on where the users live), in the output of one command vs the other. [Source](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/console_account-alias.html).

Answer (score 35):

IMHO, **the easiest way** is to edit `.aws/credentials` and `.aws/config` files manually.

It's easy and it works for Linux, Mac and Windows. Just [read this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-profiles.html) for more detail **(1 minute read)**.

`.aws/credentials` file:

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id=AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE
aws_secret_access_key=wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY

[user1]
aws_access_key_id=AKIAI44QH8DHBEXAMPLE
aws_secret_access_key=je7MtGbClwBF/2Zp9Utk/h3yCo8nvbEXAMPLEKEY
```

`.aws/config` file:

```
[default]
region=us-west-2
output=json

[profile user1]    <-- 'profile' in front of 'profile_name' (not for default)!!
region=us-east-1
output=text
```

Comment: If I have same username from different accounts, how this file would look like? Which account the `default` will consider in this case?

Comment: or try this without having to manually edit it all the time ;-)
https://github.com/runwuf/awsumfa

Answer (score 24):

Create or edit this file:

```bash
vim ~/.aws/credentials
```

List as many key pairs as you like:

```bash
[default]
aws_access_key_id=AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE
aws_secret_access_key=wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY

[user1]
aws_access_key_id=AKIAI44QH8DHBEXAMPLE
aws_secret_access_key=je7MtGbClwBF/2Zp9Utk/h3yCo8nvbEXAMPLEKEY
```

Set a local variable to select the pair of keys you want to use:

```bash
export AWS_PROFILE=user1
```

Do what you like:

```bash
aws s3api list-buckets  # any aws cli command now using user1 pair of keys
```

You can also do it command by command by including `--profile user1` with each command:

```bash
aws s3api list-buckets --profile user1
# any aws cli command now using user1 pair of keys
```

More details: [Named profiles for the AWS CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-profiles.html)

Comment: i tried to tailor this answer more to the specific question - just trying to help 

Answer (score 7):

The new aws tools now support multiple profiles.

If you configure access with the tools, it automatically creates a default in ~/.aws/config.

You can then add additional profiles - more details at: [Getting started with the AWS CLI](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-started.html#cli-multiple-profiles)

Answer (score 3):

I created a simple tool, [aaws](https://github.com/luk3thomas/aaws), to switch between AWS accounts.

It works by setting the `AWS_DEFAULT_PROFILE` in your shell. Just make sure you have some entries in your `~/.aws/credentials` file and it will easily switch between multiple accounts.

```
/tmp
$ aws s3 ls
Unable to locate credentials. You can configure credentials by running "aws configure".
```

```
/tmp
$ aaws luk3

[luk3]  /tmp
$ aws s3 ls
2013-11-05 21:40:04 luk3thomas.com
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a toolkit to switch default AWS profile.

The mechanism is physically moving the profile key to the `default` section in `config` and `credentials` files.

The better solution today should be one of the following ways:

- Use `aws` command option `--profile`.
- Use environment variable `AWS_PROFILE`.

I don't remember why I didn't use the solution of `--profile`, maybe I was not realized its existence.

However the toolkit can still be useful by doing other things. I'll add a soft switch flag by using the way of `AWS_PROFILE` in the future.

```
$ xsh list aws/cfg
[functions] aws/cfg/move
[functions] aws/cfg/set
[functions] aws/cfg/activate
[functions] aws/cfg/get
[functions] aws/cfg/delete
[functions] aws/cfg/list
[functions] aws/cfg/copy
```

Repo: https://github.com/xsh-lib/aws

Install:

```
curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/alexzhangs/xsh/master/boot | bash && . ~/.xshrc
xsh load xsh-lib/aws
```

Usage:

```
xsh aws/cfg/list
xsh aws/cfg/activate <profilename>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write shell script to set corresponding values of environment variables for each account based on user input. Doing so, you don't need to create any aliases and, furthermore, tools like ELB tools, Auto Scaling Command Line Tools will work under multiple accounts as well.

Answer (score 0):

To use an IAM role, you have to make an API call to STS:AssumeRole, which will return a temporary access key ID, secret key, and security token that can then be used to sign future API calls. Formerly, to achieve secure cross-account, role-based access from the AWS Command Line Interface (CLI), an explicit call to STS:AssumeRole was required, and your long-term credentials were used. The resulting temporary credentials were captured and stored in your profile, and that profile was used for subsequent AWS API calls. This process had to be repeated when the temporary credentials expired (after 1 hour, by default).

More details: [How to Use a Single IAM User to Easily Access All Your Accounts by Using the AWS CLI](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-use-a-single-iam-user-to-easily-access-all-your-accounts-by-using-the-aws-cli/)

Answer (score 0):

Check out [aws-vault](https://github.com/99designs/aws-vault) that has something similar to mutliple profiles in just pure aws but it also stores your access key some place more secure than a plain text file.

If you look on their [releases](https://github.com/99designs/aws-vault/releases) page there are pre-compiled binaries.

The way aws-vault works is to basically create a subshell with the right environment variables set.  In my case, I created a profile named 'chrisp' and to deploy my CDK stack I run:

`aws-vault exec chrisp yarn cdk deploy MyStackName`

where 'chrisp' is the profile name.  This works equally well with any command, in fact, a good way to test it is to do this:

`aws-vault exec chrisp sts get-caller-identity`

that will let you know that it's working and that it picks the right identity based on the provided keys.

Answer (score 0):

### CLI helper on multiple AWS accounts with MFA

Having to switch between multiple accounts is even more fun when MFA is enabled... other existing helpers out there is either an overkill or doesn't address my needs so I created this:
https://github.com/runwuf/awsumfa

**Install**

```
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/runwuf/awsumfa/main/awsumfa.bash > ~/awsumfa.bash
```

- Update your MFA ARN in `AWS_MFAARN` of `awsumfa.bash`
- Edit the sample [`credentials`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/runwuf/awsumfa/main/credentials) to add your `roles` of all accounts then place it in `~/.aws/`

**Usage**

`awsmfa ${role_name}` - choose the role defined in credentials to assume to.

`awsec2ls` - list ec2 instances in a nice format.

`awsec2 ${instance_id}` - ssm into an ec2 instance.

`installawstools` - install `aws-ssm-ec2-proxy-command.sh` makes `scp` easy to work with ec2 instances.