# `An error occurred (InvalidToken) when calling the ListBuckets operation: The provided token is malformed or otherwise invalid.` w/`aws s3 ls`

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I successfully authenticate with 2 factor but when using `aws s3 ls` I keep getting

> An error occurred (InvalidToken) when calling the ListBuckets operation: The provided token is malformed or otherwise invalid.

And I do have admin rights.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Issue was that I wasn't passing the `--region` in. e.g. `aws s3 --region us-gov-west-1 ls`. I suppose this could be set with an ENV variable too. That error message is a candidate for improvement.

Comment: Defining a default region using `export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION="{{region}}"`will save you debug time if working with non-default [AWS partitions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/Partitions.html) such as `aws-cn`.

Comment: I think that the `aws` tool just needs a better error message. If I can reproduce this again soon I'll open an upstream issue here https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues. If anyone is currently getting this error on the latest version of aws cli and it is because the region is missing, please open a new issue here https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/new/choose.

Comment: Nice, just found an issue for this opened on Sept 22, 2020, it was closed but I requested it to be re-opened. It is allegedly a server side error coming from the S3 API.  https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/5564

Comment: Working with gov cloud here, `us-gov-west-1` vs `us-west-1` fix the problem

Answer (score 23):

This error also occurs when `aws cli` reads the `aws_session_token` and `aws_security_token` declared in the `~/.aws` file, which might be associated to a previously used account. Removing both and leaving just the key and the credentials associated to the account where the bucket is will force `aws` to establish the connection.

Comment: This is also true if you have the environmental variable AWS_SESSION_TOKEN defined for another user, not only in the ~/.aws files. So, be sure to remove it from current session to not having the problem (e.g. unset AWS_SESSION_TOKEN).

Answer (score 12):

Please delete **.aws/credentials** file from your users account and reconfigure your aws cli. 
If you already associated with another account then there are high chances of this type of error.

Comment: It's not necessary to delete `~/.aws/credentials` at all.  At most, just open `~/.aws/credentials` with a text editor, delete the `aws_security_token` line from the user account you're using, save the file, and retry.

Comment: I have deleted the token line form the `~/.aws/credentials` but the error persists.

Answer (score 4):

Run aws configure

1. You may leave access key and access key id blank if you have an IAM role attached
2. Set value for 'region'

Now you will be able to successfully run 'aws s3 ls'

Else run 'aws s3 ls --region '

Answer (score 3):

If you are using AWS Single Sign-on you can pass `--profile <profile_name>` and it should solve the issue

This will work if you authentified using an AWS Single Sign-on (sso) command `aws sso login --profile <profile_name>`

Comment: On windows, in a command prompt.. aws sso login --profile <myprofile> then used sam local invoke 'HelloWorldFunction' --profile <myprofile> and it works (no Invalid Token error...

Answer (score 1):

In the .aws credentials file remove session token and it will work

Answer (score 0):

~/.aws/credentials sometimes has 2 entries for "default". Remove the one you dont need, sometime it might be just blank

Answer (score 0):

None of the other solutions worked for me.

I previously was working with another AWS account (same Organization).  I forgot that I had entered the AWS-SESSION-TOKEN, AWS-ACCESS-KEY and AWS-SECRET-ACCESS_KEY as environment variables, following whatever AWS rabbit hole instructions I had at the time.

I removed those environment variables from my ~/.zshrc file.

Then I followed the instructions in @ox's solution from here to setup multiple AWS CLI accounts:

[How to use multiple AWS accounts from the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/593334/how-to-use-multiple-aws-accounts-from-the-command-line)

Now I have multiple account profiles setup in my ~/.aws/credentials file:

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
aws_secret_access_key = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

[Backups]
aws_access_key_id = yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
aws_secret_access_key = yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
```

And I can run aws cli commands, using the --profile command line parameter if needed:

```
# the default profile - list s3 buckets
% aws s3 ls                      
2023-11-16 12:14:26 f-file-share
2023-12-14 14:07:45 oracle-export-share

# the Backups profile - list s3 buckets
% aws --profile Backups s3 ls
2023-09-12 10:34:00 files-nas-backup
2023-09-27 11:08:47 files1-nas-backup
```