# Is it possible to use two different profiles on the aws cli in the same command?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

This is related to, but different from [How to use multiple AWS accounts from the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/593334/how-to-use-multiple-aws-accounts-from-the-command-line)

I would like to sync one AWS bucket to another across two accounts. I have credentials for both accounts set up on my local machine, and I can, for example, do

```
$ aws s3 sync s3://my-first-bucket/ ./
# or
$ aws s3 sync ./ s3://my-other-bucket --profile other_account
```

But I'd like to be able to transfer from the default account directly to the bucket on the other account without needing to download and then re-upload. In other words, something like

```
aws s3 sync --profile default s3://my-first-bucket/ --profile other_account s3://my-other-bucket
```

Can this be accomplished?

Comment: Not directly, since that would mean one API call is somehow signed with two credentials, which can't happen.  For this specific case, you'll need to [setup permissions](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/copy-s3-objects-account) so one role can access both buckets cross-accounts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use a single set of credentials, you could **add a Bucket Policy** to one of the buckets, which would permit credentials from a different AWS Account to access the bucket.

#### Option 1: Push

- Use credentials from the 'source' AWS Account
- Add a Bucket Policy on the 'destination' bucket that permits `PutObject` for the credentials from the 'source' account
- Also, make sure that you specify `ACL=bucket-owner-full-control` when performing the copy, or that the destination bucket has ACLs disabled. This ensures that the AWS Account owning the destination bucket has control of the objects

#### Option 2: Pull

- Use credentials from the 'destination' AWS Account
- Add a Bucket Policy on the 'source' bucket that permits `GetObject` for the credentials from the 'destination' account
- (The ACL recommendations above are not required for 'pull' copies)

Here is sample Bucket Policy you could please on the **source bucket** to permit use of `aws s3 sync` from destination credentials:

```json
{
   "Version":"2012-10-17",
   "Statement":[
     {
       "Effect":"Allow",
       "Principal":{"AWS":"DESTINATION-CREDENTIALS-ARN"},
       "Action":[
         "s3:GetObject",
         "s3:ListBucket"
         ]
       "Resource": [
         "arn:aws:s3:::DESTINATION-BUCKET",
         "arn:aws:s3:::DESTINATION-BUCKET/*"
         ]
       }
     }
   ]
}
```

It is granting `ListBucket` to list the objects and `GetObject` to retrieve the objects. More permissions *might* be required, especially if the bucket is using KMS Keys.

Comment: Thanks - this makes sense. I don't control the destination, so I guess option 2 is what I'll have to go with

Comment: Yes. Since you have been given credentials for the destination account but you cannot change the Bucket Policy on the destination bucket, you should modify the source bucket by adding a Bucket Policy that permits access from the destination credentials. I have added a sample policy.

Answer (score 2):

AWS has a [prescriptive guidance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/prescriptive-guidance/latest/patterns/copy-data-from-an-s3-bucket-to-another-account-and-region-by-using-the-aws-cli.html) on how to do exactly that.

In a nutshell, doing what you want the way you want is not the way things are done in S3.

Basically, your model of doing things would involve two different S3 agents running with two sets of credentials. One has the permissions to read source data, another one has the permissions to write destination data, and they engage in a copying session, sending and receiving data and coordinating their progress.

It would not be technically impossible to program S3 like that, because that what you would be essentially doing if you just piped two aws commands into one another on your local machine. But it's not been done this way.

Insted, copy and sync are uniform commands running with the a single set of credentials on the target account. These credentials should have the permissions to both read the source data and write the target data. These permissions are set on the bucket level and/or the object level.

If you want the S3 copies to run completely within S3, you'll need to run the command on the target account and grant it permissions on the bucket belonging to the source account.

If you don't want to deal with cross-accounts permissions, you'll have to use some kind of an intermediate solution which would read the data from the source and write it to the target using two sets of credentials.

Done this way, it will pipe the data through the machine it runs on and eat into the request and bandwith quota on AWS, i.e. do the thing you're trying to avoid.

There are lots of third-party solutions doing that, such as [rclone](https://github.com/rclone/rclone).

Comment: Oh, `rclone` looks nice, thanks for that link! That might serve my purpose, but it seems like it would have to pipe through the machine that's running it, yeah? I'm explicitly trying to avoid that, since bandwidth isn't ideal, and it would soak all of it up for a substantial period

Comment: @kevbonham: you can run it in an Fargate container or something but yes, it will pipe it through the machine. Within S3, you will have to set up the role.